# Hi! I have a bug in my project. I don't know why Logcat swears at my retrofit object

Tags: java, android, kotlin, networking

Logcat starts swearing at this place.In my Client constructor. I do not know how to fix this error, can u help me please. Also i put my MainActivity.class code. If u want i can put my another classes and Interface. Sorry for my english.

package com.example.news.retrofit;

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class Client {

    private static final String KEY = "3eec6a8558e24defb8a30fea138c5eee";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static Client client;

    private Client() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(KEY)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }

    public static synchronized Client getInstance() {
        if (client == null) {
            client = new Client();
        }
        return client;
    }

    public IRequest getApi() {
        return retrofit.create(IRequest.class);
    }
}
```

And this is MainActivity.class code

```
package com.example.news;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.news.adapter.NewsAdapter;
import com.example.news.key.Key;
import com.example.news.retrofit.Client;
import com.example.news.retrofit.IRequest;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Retrofit retrofit;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    NewsAdapter newsAdapter;
    Key apiKey = Key.API_KEY;
    List<Article> articleList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        final String country = getCountry();
        fetchApi(country);
    }

    private void fetchApi(String country) {
        Call<HeadLines> headLinesCall = Client.getInstance().getApi().getHeadlines(country, apiKey.getValue());
        headLinesCall.enqueue(new Callback<HeadLines>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<HeadLines> call, Response<HeadLines> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getArticles() != null) {
                    articleList.clear();
                    articleList = response.body().getArticles();
                    newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(MainActivity.this, articleList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<HeadLines> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private String getCountry() {
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        return locale.getCountry().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in class Client.
Key is not Base URL.

learn more: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I Find it, and change the const, but its again swearing